# How to get variables object out of bracket, or is there any way to globally declare variables

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true, username, password);  
oModel.read('/', null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse)
{
        var dataget = JSON.stringify(oData);        
        var count = oData.results[0].Ort01;
        var Name1 = oData.results[0].Name1;
        var Kunnr = oData.results[0].Kunnr;
        alert(count + "  " +Name1 + "  " +Kunnr);   
});
```

here as you see I can get the variables inside parenthesis({ }); How to get the same variable objects outside the parenthesis something like this..

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true, username, password);  
    oModel.read('/', null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse)
    {   
    }); 
var dataget = JSON.stringify(oData);        
var count = oData.results[0].Ort01;
var Name1 = oData.results[0].Name1;
var Kunnr = oData.results[0].Kunnr;
alert(count + "  " +Name1 + "  " +Kunnr);
```

Can someone help me. Thank You

Comment: oData is data received as a callback response, so you can't get them outside. You can of course first get them inside, then declare dataget globally without var

Comment: can you suggest me how to declare globally

Comment: use "dataget=JSON.stringify(oData)" without "var" in front and you will be able to use your variable globally

Comment: @trainoasis—that doesn't declare them, it creates properties of the global object when that line of code executes.

Comment: @RobG You are correct - that's what I meant sry :)

Comment: I'd like to suggest you consider *why* you're doing this anyway. Often (not always), calling read() explicitly on an OData model, and accessing the results property from the object that is returned, is (IMHO) a bad code smell. Perhaps you're trying to accomplish something "despite" UI5's model support, rather than with it?

Comment: There's a very similar question, with answers (one from me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25494161/384366) that address this - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486738/i-want-to-pass-the-values-to-label-consuming-odata

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but the function you have declared seems to be callback function. It means that it will be executed asynchronously and therefore you cannot simply add that code just after the oModel.read line.

You, however, can declare those variable before the method call and use them in the callback method but you must realize that you cannot know when the callback function will be executed and therefore you cannot be sure when those variables will have any data.

```
var count;
var Name1;
var Kunnr;
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true, username, password);  
oModel.read('/', null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse)
{
    var dataget = JSON.stringify(oData);
    count = oData.results[0].Ort01;
    Name1 = oData.results[0].Name1;
    Kunnr = oData.results[0].Kunnr;
    alert(count + "  " +Name1 + "  " +Kunnr);
});

// Here you can reference to count those variables but you need to make sure
// that callback function is executed already
```

Above example shows how you can do it but it is not good way to do it anyway. I think you should revise the whole execution flow because of the asynchronous execution. I mean that you should understand that the execution flow will continue inside the callback function not outside of it:

```
var variableDefinedBeforeCallback = .....;
...
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true, username, password);  
oModel.read('/', null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse)
{
    var dataget = JSON.stringify(oData);
    var count = oData.results[0].Ort01;
    var Name1 = oData.results[0].Name1;
    var Kunnr = oData.results[0].Kunnr;
    alert(count + "  " +Name1 + "  " +Kunnr);

    // If you want to do something with those variables you can call any function
    // here and pass variables defined also before this callback
    anyFunction(variableDefinedBeforeCallback, count, Name1, Kunnr, ...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true, username, password);

var successCallBack = function(oData,oResponse) {
     var dataget = JSON.stringify(oData);      
     var count = oData.results[0].Ort01;
     var Name1 = oData.results[0].Name1;
     var Kunnr = oData.results[0].Kunnr;
     alert(count + "  " +Name1 + "  " +Kunnr); 
};

oModel.read('/', null, null, true, successCallBack);
```

Comment: Code only answers are disliked. Explain what the issue is and why the code fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

Just switch your mParameters.async in the read method from true to false. That will change asynchronous request to synchronous and it will work.